How to find a name from multiple sheets and then mark yes in a master sheet?
I have a list of all of the names of the children in my school on a master sheet. Then on multiple other sheets, which we use to record star of the week each week, I want to be able to search through all of those sheets and if they have had their name written as star of the week on any of those weeks, I want to be able to have a formulae that will mark yes next to their name on the master sheet. The sheets are named as dates if that makes a difference to the formulae e.g. 24/03/2024, 17/03/2024 etc
Is there an if formula that I can use for this?
To give more context, let's say:
On the master sheet, John Bear is in A4.
I then want to search through sheets named 29/09/23, 06/10/23, 22/09/23 to find if John Bear is also listed
If it makes a difference then names would be listed in the B column in all those sheets.
If John Bear appears in those sheets, I want it to say yes. If it doesn't, it says no.
Thanks in advance for your help
I haven't tried anything yet as I'm a clueless teacher trying to make a job easier
